# J2EE:error in displaying ERROR page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

i have created a jsp contains

```
<% 
  int i=10;
  if(i==10)
  throw new ArithmeticException("ItsMyGenExcepetion"); 
%>
```

i have made entry in web.xml

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.ArithmeticException</exception-type>
<location>/errordisplay.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

i have my errordisply.jsp contains

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
```

in body

```
The page contain error <%= exception %>
```

but its not showing the error page....

Comment: are you not redirect to the error page or in the error page the message is not displayed?

Comment: The page is displaying 
500:server side error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i got my quetions solution but not the answer

when i use Eclipse's (SDK 3.2) web browser...

the page is showing

> The page cannot be displayed  There is
>   a problem with the page you are trying
>   to reach and it cannot be displayed.
>
> ---
>
> Please try the following:
>
> Open the localhost:8080 home page, and
>   then look for links to the information
>   you want.  Click the  Refresh button,
>   or try again later.
>
> Click  Search to look for information
>   on the Internet.  You can also see a
>   list of related sites.
>
> HTTP 500 - Internal server error 
>   Internet Explorer

where as,when i use mozilla firefox for the same url,it works.

but why???

Comment: Are you using IE to test? If yes, then your error page must be greater than 512KB in size for IE to render the page. Otherwise, IE will render its default error page. Firefox renders the page whatever its size.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<%@ page errorPage="/errordisplay.jsp" %>
```

to the JSP that is throwing the exception.