# JSP Exception Handling

Tags: java, jsp

I have 2 simple JSP to check navigation to error page on occurrence of exceptions:

calculation_page.jsp -having the tag - `<%@ page errorPage="error_page.jsp"%>`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%-- include custom error page in this jsp code --%>
<%@ page errorPage="error_page.jsp" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>calculation page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <% 
      int i = 10;

      // This line will create an error so error page will be called
             i = i / 0;
       %>
    </body>
</html>
```

error_page.jsp - error page having the tag - <%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page isErrorPage = "true"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*" %>

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE> custom error page </TITLE>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h2>Your application has generated an error</h2>
       <h3>Please check for the error given below</h3>
       <b>Exception:</b><br> 
       <font color="red"><%= exception.toString() %></font>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when an exception occurs, instead of going from 1st page to the 2nd one, it gives an error – “HTTP 500 Internal Server Error” and the browser says: “The website cannot display the page”.

Kindly help.

Comment: But the problem is I copy pasted your code in my eclipse project and ran it. No 500 error came and I managed to move from page 1 to 2

Answer (score 2):

your error page looks *OK* but your errorGenerator page should look like :

```
<%@page errorPage="/errorPage.jsp" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        int i = 10;
        i = i / 0;
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note:`errorPage="/errorPage.jsp"` in page directive

*The errorPage attribute of a page directive specifies an alternate page to use as an error page,*

Answer (score 1):

Guys, just came across this link: [J2EE:error in displaying ERROR page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470750/j2eeerror-in-displaying-error-page).

It says IE needs the error page to atleast 512kb in size. I tried the page in firefox it is working perfectly fine.

Then, increased the size of the error page including images, now it works fine in IE 8 with the page directive tag as well as with global xml tags.

Dont know why, but its a weird thing. Both IE 7 and 8 have this issue. 512 kb is a pretty big size for an error page.

Comment: I was having same problem in eclipse browser, if I set isErrorPage="false", then it will redirect to error page but of course I couldn't get the <%=exception%> to work. After reading your reply , I tried it in Microsoft edge and it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you declare the error page in your `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>error_page.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

@org.life.java
Thanks for the reply. I ran your code without any change to web.xml i.e. without adding a error page tag, it is still giving the same HTTP 500 error. I think the problem might be with some tomcat configuration. Not sure though. I am using Tomcat v 5.5.

@mvg
Thanks for the reply. May be then there is some other configuration issue.

@cherouvim
Thanks for the reply. I declared the error page in web.xml as shown by you and removed the page attribute from the jsp. It gives me the same HTTP 500 error. Even tried with exception-type tag in xml, but it gave the same result. Here is my web.xml:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    abc
    
  12

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>PortalServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>PortalServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.portal.batch.PortalServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PortalServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PortalServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>testDefault.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>   
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error_page.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```